# Rails - Update Foreign Key Automatically When Record Is Saved

Tags: ruby-on-rails, foreign-keys

I have two ActiveRecord models, `Assignment` and `Instruction`. `Assignment` belongs to `Instruction`.

When a new assignment is saved I want to trigger a callback that inserts the foreign key in the assignment based an another attribute in `Assignment`. In other words, if `assignment.assignment_type` = `instruction.name`, insert that instruction's id as the primary key in the assignment.

It seems like you would use a Rails callback. But I'm not sure how to do this without making the models talk to each other, which I've gathered is a bad idea.

**Edit 1**

Following mjnissim's advice below I implemented this, which works:

```
class Assignment < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :game_type, :title, :instruction_id

  belongs_to :instruction

  before_save :set_instruction

  private

  def set_instruction
    instruction = Instruction.where(:name => self.game_type).first
    self.instruction = instruction
  end

end
```

However, I was hesitant to write that `set_instruction` method because I thought models couldn't speak to each other without breaking the MVC structure. But it's actually okay?

Comment: To be extremely honest, I do not know which theory it breaks, if it does at all! ;-) I don't think it would break MVC in any case, and it stands to reason that models would have some level of working with other models without becoming intertwined. Think for yourself a moment and try to imagine sterile models that know of no other object... it would seem like trying to keep some holy principle at the expense of being practical. You might also look into DCI and the "Concerns" folder and its use [http://www.artima.com/articles/dci_vision.html](http://www.artima.com/articles/dci_vision.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nifty,

Models knowing about each other or using callbacks is not a bad idea. It's a good idea.

However, I didn't fully understand your question bro. Do you have only one assignment per Instruction?

Anyway, there are plenty of callbacks that can be found [on this page](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html), but I think the one you're looking for is `before_save`. Try putting this in the `Assignment` model:

```
before_save do
  if some_condition_is_true
    assign_this = to_that
  end
  true
end
```

Notice the `true` at the end. If you don't return `true` it can cancel the save in some of the callbacks (read the docs I linked to to find out which). (Needless to say - you might need to cancel the save sometimes so use correctly...)

Another useful thing you might want to use in your callbacks is `_changed?`. If you have an attribute called `title` for instance, you can ask something like this:

```
if title_changed?
  ... do things...
end
```

`_changed?` comes free of charge, built in with Rails.

If you need clarifications please comment and I'll try and update my answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot for detailed answer. Please check Edit 1 in my original question.

Answer (score 1):

If Assignment `belongs_to` Instruction then an Assignment has an `instruction_id` attribute.  To set `instruction_id` you only need

```
assignment.instruction = instruction
```

Comment: mjnissim got more to the heart of my question, but this is helpful so +1!